# How to re-render the page when changing language in @ shopify / react-i18n?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, shopify

The translations do not change when changing the language. I am using MobX to store the state of the language. Changing the language changes the locale in the I18nContext.Provider, but the text on the page does not change.

My hook.

```
import {useI18n} from "@shopify/react-i18n";
import enTrans from "../../translate/en.json";
import frTrans from "../../translate/fr.json";

export const UseI18nHook = () => {
  console.log('hook1');
  return useI18n({
  id: 'App',
  fallback: 'fr',
  translations(locale) {
    return locale === "en" ? enTrans : frTrans;
  },
})};
```

My translate provider

```
import React from "react";
import {inject, observer} from "mobx-react";
import {I18nContext, I18nManager} from '@shopify/react-i18n';

const TranslateWrapper = inject(stores => ({
  activeEnglish: stores.LocalizeStore.activeEnglish
}))(observer(({activeEnglish, children}) => {

  return(
    <I18nContext.Provider value={new I18nManager({
      locale: activeEnglish ? 'en' : 'fr',
      onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
      },

    })}>
        {children}
    </I18nContext.Provider>
  )
}));

export default TranslateWrapper;
```

In page i use `const [i18n] = UseI18nHook();` and `i18n.translate('App.InstallPage.installTitle')`

Answer (score 2):

the way I would implement it is as follows:
first i will use a Custom translation hook to handle all the logic for me

```
import * as translations from "./Translations";

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function useTranslation() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("ar");
  const [fallbackLanguage, setFallbackLanguage] = useState("en");

  //this is optional if the language is rtl
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.dir = language === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr";
  }, [language]);

  const translate = (key) => {
    const keys = key.split(".");

    return (
      getNestedTranslation(language, keys) ?? //return the value of the key in the selected language
      getNestedTranslation(fallbackLanguage, keys) ?? //return the value of the key in fallback language if there is no translation found in the main langrage
      key // return the key itself if there is no translation found in the fallback language
    );
  };

  return {
    language,
    setLanguage,
    fallbackLanguage,
    setFallbackLanguage,
    t: translate,
  };
}

function getNestedTranslation(language, keys) {
  return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    return obj?.[key];
  }, translations[language]);
}
```

then have a folder called Translations which has index.js

```
export * as en from "./en.json";
export * as ar from "./ar.json";
//any other languages
```

and the JSON files that has the translations

en.json:

```
"hello":"Welcome"
```

ar.json:

```
"hello": "مرحبا"
```

In page i use const {t} = useTranslation(); and t('hello')

you can also have nested keys like this one

```
"months": [
    "feb",
    "jan",
    "mar"
]
```

and use it like so: t("months.1") (will return feb)

in the component that will change the language do the following and it should rerender :

```
cosnt {setLanguage}=useTranslation();

const handleLangChange=(lang)=>{
setLanguage(lang);
}
```